# Creating a Condition variable in R based on values of three different variables

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, grouping

I need to create a variable called 'Group' where participants are either labeled as being in Group0, Group1, Group2, or Group3. The group they are assigned to is based on their race, gender, and sexuality (which have been numerically coded).

I am definately messing up with the operators. There are three different combinations of the three variables for Groups 1 and 2. For 0 and 3, there is only one.

Here is what I have:

```
data <- 
  data %>%  
  group_by() %>%
  ifelse(race == 1 & gen == 1 & sexor == 1, Group0 | race == 1 & gen == 2 & sexor == 1 | race == 2 & gen == 1 & sexor == 1 || race == 1 & gen == 1 & sexor == 2, Group1 || race == 2 & gen == 2 & sexor == 1 || race == 2 & gen == 1 & sexor == 2 || race == 1 & gen == 2 & sexor == 2, Group2 | race == 2 & gen == 2 & sexor == 2, Group3)
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that are not right in your code. You are using `group_by()` without any argument, and `ifelse()` with far too many arguments. You might want to check on some R tutorials such as https://www.tidyverse.org/learn/ before attacking any real word coding problem. Also, it would be difficult to answer any question if you don't provide us with some toy dataset so that we can show you the output. To properly answer your question though, you should use the function `case_when()` instead of `ifelse()`.

Comment: As Dan mentioned, `dplyr::case_when` is your friend here. Try `data %>% mutate(group = case_when(race == 1 & gen == 1 & sexor == 1 ~ "Group0", race == 1 & gen == 2 ... (continued)` I would also suggest taking a step back and practicing a bit

Comment: It has been a while since I have coded; just needed to be pointed in the right direction, thank you, I got it!